# Hiera command line: How do I view all data in the hierarchy for a given node?

Tags: puppet, hiera

just testing out hiera and I'd like to be able to view all the available data (variable=value pairs) in the hierarchy for a given node.

My Hiera hierarchy is configured as:

```
---
:backends:
  - yaml
  - json
:yaml:
  :datadir: C:\Puppet\hieradata
:hierarchy: 
  - "Env/%{::env}"
  - common
```

I can run the following to return node1's value for 'some-common' variable :

```
>hiera some-common ::env=node1
data
```

What I'd like to be able to see is all the variable=value pairs available to node1 in the hierarchy, is this possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I'm afraid this is not possible. Closest thing you could do is dump facts for specific node:

```
facter -y > node.yml
```

And then use them for look for specific keys:

```
hiera -y node.yml my_class:arg -d
```

this way you will be able to access Hiera keys based on operating system, domain, etc. (depends on your hierarchy defined in `hiera.yaml`).

Yet another option is to ssh into puppet master node. And use `puppet lookup` (should be available since Puppet 4). `lookup` is using by default Hiera backend (again requires `hiera.yaml` config file).

```
puppet lookup resolv_conf::nameservers --node mynode.example.net
```

or more verbose version:

```
puppet lookup resolv_conf::nameservers --merge deep --environment production --explain --node mynode.example.net
```

Comment: This just made my day. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

I found another workaround - you can add top level key to your yaml data:

```
node-data:
  hosts:
    - localhost:3367
    - company.com
  dns: 8.8.8.8
  policy:
    retries: 3
    timeout: 5
```

and do puppet lookup with merge for this top level key, e.g.:

```
puppet lookup --merge hash/deep node_data
```